# Wifi connected but internet not working

Tags: wireless

There is problem with my wifi connection. Its shows as connected but still internet is not working. I tried making my mobile as hotspot then try to connect my laptop to it, it worked. So problem is only when I connect to my wifi router.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved by referring to instructions given here: https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/internet#TOC-Disable-power-management-for-the-wireless-card

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

This solved my issue.